# How to join this face properly?

Tags: faces

I have this face i want to connect but the sides have like over 10 verts, but i want to make it join smoothly with the curve. I dont know how to do it (**red part**)

The red part will follow and join the **blue part** in the end.

How can I join them witout altering the face of the mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should to add more edge loops in blue side , Equal with red side to join , then add one loop between red and blue side and Bevel to have a curvy conection .

Upload Blend file to show you how it's possible .

Comment: where can i upload the blender file?

Comment: Upload here :  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/